# ipsec.conf file with dynamic ipv6 address

Tags: ipv6, ipsec

I have been able to get strongswan ipsec tunnel between 2 linux machines with static ipv6 address. For example, a segment of my ipsec.conf file looks like

```
left=2000::1
leftcert=/home/root/ABCDCert.der
leftid="C=XX, O=Test, CN=ABCD.org"
right=2000::3
rightid="C=XX, O=Test, CN=XYZ.org"
```

Now, i replace the left linux machine with dynamic ipv6 address and right one still is static,but address is different

It is as follows

```
left=2001:aaaa:bbbb:cccc:b499:4c00:191:19ef
leftcert=/home/root/ABCDCert.der
leftid="C=XX, O=Test, CN=ABCD.org"
right=2001:aaaa:bbbb:cccc::1
rightid="C=XX, O=Test, CN=XYZ.org"
```

The left machine has a dynamic ipv6 from a RA server. `(2001:aaaa:bbbb:cccc:b499:4c00:191:19ef)`
The right machine has a static ipv6 `2001:aaaa:bbbb:cccc::1/64`
The tunnel does not come up with this setting. I am able to `ping6` between the two machines. I must be doing something wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Could be this issue here: https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/803

Comment: I noticed that after i delete the dynamic ipv6 from the ipse.conf file, the tunnel is up!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that after i delete the dynamic ipv6 from the ipse.conf file, the tunnel is up!